# How set MAC address filtering on linux?

Tags: arp, netfilter

I need to block any incoming connection from a MAC address different from a specific one (which is static and well known).

This MAC address should generate only non-IP connection: this is the reason why I don't know if ARPtables could be the best solution.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You'll have to provide more informations on the network setup, the current system's network configuration (interfaces...), the network protocols involved and the reason (rather than only the method) for having to block. Is this ARP (because arptables blocks only ARP, but you write non-IP which is not specific enough)? Without these additional informations an answer might miss important points.

Comment: I think this question ask here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/519480/iptables-allow-access-from-certain-mac-addresses

Comment: Is this  NCP ie NetWare ? Or the transport protocol in OSI ? If it isn't ARP, SNA ?

Comment: I have an ETH interface with a static MAC address: this interface is used only for AVB, hence no ARP and IP. This interface is directly connected to another ETH interface with a well-know static MAC address. My primary goal is to block any  connection from different MAC address and connections with EtherType in Ethernet Frame different from the AVB one.

Comment: I didn't know about AVB....  reading the description of it :  big hops and complexity to make 802.3 do that TokenBus did early on... but market forces  and competition....

Comment: Yes, you're right. However my question is not related to the AVB protocol itself but on a way to perform filtering on a MAC address even if no IP or ARP are present

Comment: It would help to add your comments about the use case inside the question (with [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/610512/edit)).

Comment: So this can't be done with iptables nor arptables. You can do this with a bridge and ebtables, or with an interface and tc, or with an interface or a bridge and nftables. Using tc is difficult, using a bridge requires to create an internal bridge just for the sake of filtering, using nftables on an interface currently works only for ingress, but might fit the bill. So what would you like? There are even more methods available like XDP. The later and maybe tc or nftables can sometimes even be accelerated directly on the NIC, but I don't known much about this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with this command:
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 12:34:56:78:9A:BC -j DROP
just replace 12:34:56:78:9A:BC with the mac address that you what to block

Comment: I'm not so sure: I think the eth packet is processed by iptables only if EtherType in Ethernet Frame is IPv4 or IPv6. Do you think the packet is always processed by iptables even if it is not a standard IP packet?